# sun.misc.Contended is not a member of package sun.misc Scala

Tags: java, scala, java-11, java-platform-module-system

I'm updating JDK version from 8 to 11 an get the issue with some concurrent data structure.

```
error: type Contended is not a member of package sun.misc
[ERROR] @sun.misc.Contended
[ERROR]           ^
[ERROR] one error found
```

Is there a way to work around this? I'm using Scala `2.12.8`?

Comment: Are you using this annotation in your code?

Comment: @JornVernee Exactly yes. To prevent false sharing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using this annotation in your user code, <strike>you should just remove it, as it's not doing anything.</strike>

Hotspot allows use of this annotation in privileged code. From [classFileParser.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/hotspot/share/classfile/classFileParser.cpp#l2134):

```
AnnotationCollector::ID
AnnotationCollector::annotation_index(const ClassLoaderData* loader_data,
                                      const Symbol* name) {
  const vmSymbols::SID sid = vmSymbols::find_sid(name);
  // Privileged code can use all annotations.  Other code silently drops some.
  const bool privileged = loader_data->is_the_null_class_loader_data() ||
                          loader_data->is_platform_class_loader_data() ||
                          loader_data->is_anonymous();
  switch (sid) {
...
    case vmSymbols::VM_SYMBOL_ENUM_NAME(jdk_internal_vm_annotation_Contended_signature): {
      if (_location != _in_field && _location != _in_class) {
        break;  // only allow for fields and classes
      }
      if (!EnableContended || (RestrictContended && !privileged)) {
        break;  // honor privileges
      }
      return _jdk_internal_vm_annotation_Contended;
    }
```

If the annotation is used outside of privileged code it is normally ignored.

---

**But!** it looks like there is a production level flag to enable `@Contended` specifically for non-privileged classes.

In that case you can use `--add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.vm.annotation=<your module>` when compiling, and import the annotation from `jdk.internal.vm.annotation` instead.

Then when running the application use `-XX:-RestrictContended`.

Of course this is an internal API that should rather not be depended upon. However, for migration to later versions of Java, the above flags can be used as a temporary solution.